# linking url in an article from php dashboard does not work

Tags: php, url, tinymce

I have a dashboard designed in php for the client from where he is able to add new stories/articles on the main site using the tiny mce editor, just similar to a joomla article. The problem is that when a url is linked then it appends to the main site for some reason. e.g

http://example.com/"http://careers.virginmedia.com//"

I have tried every format for the url, but doesn't work. Please can someone help me with this.

The following code adds the content

```
function addSponsoredAd()
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $db = new Connection(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

        $userID = $_SESSION['user']['userID'];

        $ID = getNextID('sponsoredAds');

        $imgTmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

        $image = basename(strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $_FILES['image']['name'])));

        $info = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);

        $filename = $image;

        $imageFolder = '../mediaLibrary/sponsoredAds/';

        $imageDestination = $imageFolder.$filename;

        move_uploaded_file($imgTmp, $imageDestination);

        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $position = $_POST['position'];
        $status = $_POST['status'];
        $content = $_POST['content'];

        $parameters = array(
            'table' => 'sponsoredAds',
            'fieldsAndValues' => array(
                            'userID' => $userID,
                            'title' => $title,
                            'description' => $description,
                            'status' => $status,
                            'position' => $position,
                            'content'=> $content,
                            'dateAdded' => datetime()
                            )
        );

        $db->insert($parameters);

        if($imgTmp != '')
        {
            $parameters = array(
                'table' => 'sponsoredAds',
                'fieldsAndValues' => array(
                    'logo' => $imageDestination
                ),
            'conditions' => 'WHERE ID = "'.$ID.'"'
            );

            $db->update($parameters);
        }

        setMessage('Added a new sponsored ad: '.$title, 1);
        header('Location: '.BASE_URL.'dashboard/sponsoredAds');
    }
}
```

The code below displays it

```
function getSponsoredListings()
    {
        $db = new Connection(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        $result = $db->query('
            SELECT *
            FROM sponsoredAds   
            ORDER BY position
        ');

        $items='';

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $items .= '
                <div id="search-results">
                    <div class="search-result '.$class.'" id="searchResult'.$row['ID'].'">
                        <a href="sponsored-posts/'.$row['ID'].'">
                        <div class="img-container">
                            <img src="'.BASE_URL.str_replace('../', '', $row['logo']).'" alt="'.$row['title'].'" />
                        </div><!-- End img container -->
                        <h3>'.$row['title'].'</h3>
                        <p>'.$row['content'].'</p>
                        <div class="cont">'.$row['description']
                        .'</div><!-- End cont -->
                        </a>
                    </div><!-- End search result -->
                </div><!-- End search results -->
                ';
                $count++;
        }
        return $items;
    }
```

The tinymce page code:

```
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>_style/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>_style/dashboard.css" />
    <link href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" /> 
    <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>_scripts/functions.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>dashboard/_scripts/functions.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>_scripts/notify.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>_scripts/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>_scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>_scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector:'textarea',
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
    });
        var BASE_URL = '<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>';
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
                // Location of TinyMCE script
                script_url : '<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>_scripts/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

        mode : 'textareas',
        plugins : 'jbimages,paste,fullscreen,media,table',
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
        theme : 'advanced',
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : 'bold,italic,underline,|,bullist,numlist,|,link,unlink,image,jbimages,|,formatselect,removeformat,code, fullscreen, media,|,tablecontrols',
        theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "tablecontrols",
        table_styles : "Header 1=header1;Header 2=header2;Header 3=header3",
        table_cell_styles : "Header 1=header1;Header 2=header2;Header 3=header3;Table Cell=tableCel1",
        table_row_styles : "Header 1=header1;Header 2=header2;Header 3=header3;Table Row=tableRow1",
        table_cell_limit : 100,
        table_row_limit : 5,
        table_col_limit : 5,
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : '',
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : '',
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : '',
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : 'top', 
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : 'left',
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        theme_advanced_blockformats : 'Paragraph=p,Heading=h4,Leading=h3',
        relative_urls : false,

        valid_elements : '*[*]',
        valid_styles :  {'span' : 'text-decoration', 'img' : 'vertical-align,border,margin-top,margin-bottom,margin-left,margin-right,float'},
        width: '100%',
        height: '400',
        extended_valid_elements: "embed[width|height|name|flashvars|src|bgcolor|align|play|loop|quality|allowscriptaccess|type|pluginspage]",
        media_strict: false
    });

            $('#name').keyup(function(){
                $('#permalink').val($('#name').val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9-]+/g, '').toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '-').replace('--', '-'));
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```
<h1>Add a New Sponsored Ad</h1>

<form action="<?php addSponsoredAd(); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="image">Logo</label>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />

    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />

    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <textarea name="description" id="description"><?php echo $info['description']; ?></textarea>

    <label for="content">Content</label>
    <textarea class="tinymce" name="content" id="content"><?php echo $info['content']; ?></textarea>

    <!-- <label for="position">Position</label>
    <input type="text" name="position" id="position" /> -->

    <label for="status"><input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status" value="1" /> Active?</label>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add Sponsored Ad" />

</form>
```

Comment: Can you show us some code that generates the links?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: @chris this is the code that displays it

Comment: @jay ummm i have tried formats like "link.com" "www.link.com"  I have also added the code

Comment: @user3297381 Which line is generating the incorrect link? Can you show us some sample output of this code?

Comment: @chris, this code is generating a page that contains content written in an editor, it also contains a link and the url is of an external website, but instead it is appending that external link at the end of my website link, just like i have explained above.

Comment: @user3297381 Right now, there is only one `<a>` tag in the code you have posted and it seems that this is designed to link to an URL formatted like `http://mypage.com/sponsored-ads/1234` so I don't think this is the one you have a problem with. Unless you show me some output so I can see which link gives you trouble I don't think I can help you.

Comment: @chris have a look now, basically the first function is just fetching information and saving it into the database and the second is displaying it, the problem is with the tiny mce editor itself, any ideas?

Comment: @user3297381 Ah, so what you are saying is that the link is already converted to the wrong format on the client side. In this case we would need to have a look at the front-end code where you set up tinyMCE.

Comment: Yes I have added that for you

Answer (score 0):

You are using TinyMCE with the `relative_urls = false` option. From looking at the [TinyMCE docs on URL conversion](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/url_conversion.php) I think you should instead drop that option and add `convert_urls: false`.

Comment: sorry for replying late, it did not work :( tried both dropping it and adding convert-urls...